# Hopf fibration is a riemannian submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hopf-fibration

Reference: Peter Petersen, Riemannian Geometry, 3rd edition, Example 1.1.5

**Hopf fibration** $F: S^3(1) \to S^2 (1/2)$ is defined by
$$F(z,w) = \left(\frac{1}{2} (|w|^2 - |z|^2), z\overline{w}\right)$$
if we think of $S^3(1) \subset C^2$ and $S^2(1/2) \subset R \oplus C$.
I want to show that $F$ is a Riemannian submersion.

**Definition**: a **Riemannian submersion** $F:(M,g_M) \to(N,g_N)$ is a submersion $F:M \to N$ such that for each $p\in M$, $DF:\ker(DF)^\perp \to T_{f(p)}N$ is a linear isometry. That is, if $v,w \in T_pM$ are perpendicular to the kernel of $DF: T_pM \to T_{F(p)N}$, then
$$g_M(v,w) = g_N(DF(v),DF(w)).$$

To show that $F$ is a Riemannian submersion, I tried to find $\ker (DF)$. Since I don't know the method to find $DF$ when $F$ is not a real function, I set $F$ as a real-valued function as below.
$$F(a,b,c,d) = \left(\frac{1}{2} ((a^2 - b^2) - (c^2 -d^2)), ac+bd, bc-ad\right).$$
Then I computed $$DF =\begin{pmatrix} a & -b & -c & d \\ c & d & a & b \\ -d & c& b& -a\end{pmatrix}$$
To find a kernel, I used elementary row operations to an augmented matrix $(DF|0)$. This calculation is very messy, so I am not sure whether this method is right or not.

p.s. I know there are similar questions(
[The hopf fibration is a submersion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2663460/the-hopf-fibration-is-a-submersion)
[Hopf fibration is a submersion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95707/hopf-fibration-is-a-submersion?noredirect=1&lq=1) ), but I didn't understand their answers. Moreover, What I want to do is to find $\ker(DF)$.

Comment: If it is not too late, I can post rather easier computation compared to the posts you mentioned.

Comment: @Wylnorr Yes please!

Comment: Have you read Wilhelm map $H(z,w)=(\frac{1}{2}(|w|^2-|z|^2),z\bar{w})$; $H:\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ which characterizes the Hopf fibration? I think this map may exist in Petersen's book. I am not sure.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4095331/272127